# Plotting Sentinel 2a images on Earth Engine map shows missing chunks of images interrupting continuous sweeps

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am by no means knowledgable in this field so I apologise for the lack of a better description in the title, but (shown below) it seems that a lot has been masked out. This was taken from a short 5 day period and only start to fill in after several months of composites. The code is just importing and representing:

```js
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2018-07-01','2018-07-5')
  .select(['B4','B3','B2'])
  .median()
  .divide(10000);

Map.addLayer(image, {min:0, max:0.3});
```

What is causing this masking? Shouldn't the image be continuous along the stripes?

[image]

Even the scene classification is masked so I can't see whether the pixels were defective, and when I add the `SCL` band in the `.select()`, I get this error most of the time:

```
Layer 1: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with an incompatible band was encountered. Mismatched type for band 'SCL':
Expected: Type<Short<0, 255>>.
  Actual: Type<Integer<0, 65535>>.
          Image ID: 20180609T103019_20180609T103214_T31TGK
This band might require an explicit cast.
```

I didn't know if this was correlated so I thought I should add it in; apologies if it is unrelated.

Comment: I have been encountering similar problem while viewing data from Sentinel 2. I don't know if it is satellite specific but this is very inconvenient. Initially I thought maybe the satellite images with a lot of clouds are erased but then upon closer inspection, I found it to not be the case. Any help would be highly appreciated people! Regards,
Shash[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVc5K.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVc5K.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The entire S2 image archive is still being uploaded onto the google earth engine servers which explains the missing S2 data. However, the data is available to download through the Scihub portal if you need access to it https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home.